# OBIEE Multiple Fact Table In Single Business Model?

Tags: obiee

I'm sorry for images but I think this is the best way for expaining the problem.

**Relationships in Physical Layer as below;**

[image]

**Relationships in Logical Layer as below;**
[image]

**When I try to get data between 2 fact table I get the result as below;**
[image]

Lastly, here is sql code of my report;
[image]

So, I'm sure that there is no problem between relationships..How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content levels in the fact LTS to "Grand Total" for the non-conformed dimensions and tie the measures to the grand total level of the non-conformed dimensions as well.

https://greatobi.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/making-dims-facts-work-together/

Comment: Hi Chris,  I created a new logical dimension hierarchy for Dim Warehouses and I set it's logical level as Grand Total for Order Total measure in Fact Order table. Now it works but wrong. Please see the result of report; https://pasteboard.co/I5l0a6n.png and check this what I did; https://pasteboard.co/I5l0K2L.png

Comment: Why should that be wrong? You get the grand total since Order Total can't be split by warehouse

Comment: This result is not true; https://pasteboard.co/I5l0a6n.png Because Order Total can not be same for all warehouse, so this result is not meaningful.. How can I split by warehouse? I dont understand what is wrong for relationship or BMM model. I checked everything many times

Comment: According to your design, the Dim Warehouses is NOT related to Fact Orders. Hence the Order measure can NOT be split by Warehouse because is has no notion whatsoever of how it relates to warehouses. It's your model, not mine. Hence the grand total for the Order measure with regards to warehouses is the grand total. Period.

Comment: Yes, there is no relationship but normally we can write sql by using some tables to get that result. Problem is here, how we can tell to Obi that? What is wrong for model? What should be it? If I use single fact table it is not problem, problem is how can I use two fact table in single bmm?

Comment: "Yes, there is no relationship but normally we can write sql by using some tables to get that result."  HOW would you write that to make the split?! Based on your model you also can't do a time split. Your model or data at its base is flawed. OBI can do just about anything but if your data doesn't support what you want to do then you're blocked.